# .NET MAUI Blazor Hybrid local images not loading

Tags: c#, razor, blazor, maui, mudblazor

Working on a .NET MAUI Blazor Hybrid and using MudBlazor for my UI.  Images are currently not loading in my app. I have the following declared in the project file:

```
<!-- Images -->
<MauiImage Include="Resources\Images\*" />
```

Example call in the razor UI:

```
<MudAvatar Image="resources/images/foo.jpeg" Size="Size.Large" />
```

I should also mention if I call an external image in the razor UI it works. Following example image loads without any issues:

```
<MudAvatar Image="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1313493454710857730/ddYgxm9j_400x400.jpg" Size="Size.Large" />
```

I am testing the app in the Android Emulator and confirmed the image properties Build Action is set to MauiImage.

Am I missing something? Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are numerous existing questions about images in MAUI Blazor

Comment: Have your tried just Image="foo.jpeg"  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to create a new folder named images below the project's wwwroot folder.  Such as:

[image]

And then you can display the image such as:

```
<MudAvatar Image="images/foo.jpeg" Size="Size.Large" />
```